# How to set up siblings?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Hi I am a high school student who is new to coding with BeautifulSoup 4.9.0(?) using Python 3.10 and I was having trouble with siblings. I have been using an online resources to try and understand how siblings work and what each part does but when I run the code I run into errors and  I am confused on how to fix it to make it work properly. when i run my code I get this error 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'tr'.

This is the code I have so far, can somebody please help met to figure out what I should be doing.

```
from surllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.error import HTTPError
from urllib.error import URLError
import re

html2 = urlopen('http://www.pythonscraping.com/pages/page3.html')
bs = BeautifulSoup(html2, 'html.parser')
for sibling in bs.find('title', {'id':'giftList'}).tr.next_siblings:
    print(sibling)
print('siblings')

html3 = urlopen('http://www.pythonscraping.com/pages/page3.html')
bs2 = BeautifulSoup(html3, 'html.parser')
print(bs2.find('img',
              {'src':'../img/gifts/img1.jpg'})
     .parent.previous_sibling.get_text())
print('sibling image')
```

Answer (score 0):

The tag with the `id="giftList"` is `<table>`, not `<title>`:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get("http://www.pythonscraping.com/pages/page3.html")
bs = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

for sibling in bs.find("table", {"id": "giftList"}).tr.next_siblings:
    print(sibling)
```

Prints:

```html
<tr class="gift" id="gift1"><td>
Vegetable Basket
</td><td>
This vegetable basket is the perfect gift for your health conscious (or overweight) friends!
<span class="excitingNote">Now with super-colorful bell peppers!</span>
</td><td>
$15.00
</td><td>
<img src="../img/gifts/img1.jpg"/>
</td></tr>


<tr class="gift" id="gift2"><td>
Russian Nesting Dolls
</td><td>
Hand-painted by trained monkeys, these exquisite dolls are priceless! And by "priceless," we mean "extremely expensive"! <span class="excitingNote">8 entire dolls per set! Octuple the presents!</span>
</td><td>
$10,000.52
</td><td>
<img src="../img/gifts/img2.jpg"/>
</td></tr>

...and so on.
```